# Locking folders in slurm

Tags: slurm

I am using slurm to train models. Now, I need to share the computing resources with my groupmates, but I have some confidential data stored in the slurm. Therefore, I wish to add a password to a certain folder. But I don't have the root permission so it's difficult for me to use apps like Cryptkeeper and so on to easily manage the folder password.

So, is there any way that I can add password to my folders on the slurm system without the root permission and GUI? Thanks a lot!